# Lookup row in another table that has the maximum value among all rows that are related to the current record

Tags: powerpivot

There are two tables, say A and B. I want to create a calculated column in A with the following data from B. For a given row *i* in A, I want the ID of that row in B that has the maximum value among all rows that are related to row *i*.

For example:

```
Table A:
ID 
1 
2


Table B:
ID | A_ID | Value 
x  | 1    | 100
y  | 1    | 200
x  | 2    | 400
y  | 2    | 300


Desired result:

Table A:
ID | B_ID 
1  | y 
2  | x
```

I hope this is clear. A SQL statement as the following one would do the job.

```
update A set B_ID = (select B.ID from B where B.A_ID = ID order by Value desc limit 1)
```

The closest I got so far was with `LOOKUPVALUE`, but it gave me the value of the global MAX, instead of the MAX within the relevant window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
=SELECTCOLUMNS( 
    FILTER(B,[Flow]=CALCULATE(MAX(B[Value])) && 
             A[ID]=B[A_ID]),"some name", [ID])
```